# How to create taxonomy archive that can display list of post of that taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I am creating wordpress template that can use custom taxonomy(like categories). i want that every time i click the post's category it shows the list of post of that category. here is my category.php.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"><h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1></div>
    <div id="menu"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="blog">
        <?php $post = $posts[0]; // Hack. Set $post so that the_date() works. ?>
            <?php /* If this is a category archive */ if (is_category()) { ?>
                <h2>Archive for the &#8216;<?php single_cat_title(); ?>&#8217; Category:</h2>
            <?php /* If this is a tag archive */ } elseif( is_tag() ) { ?>
                <h2>Posts Tagged &#8216;<?php single_tag_title(); ?>&#8217;</h2>
            <?php /* If this is a daily archive */ } elseif (is_day()) { ?>
                <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>:</h2>
            <?php /* If this is a monthly archive */ } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
                <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('F, Y'); ?>:</h2>
            <?php /* If this is a yearly archive */ } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
                <h2>Archive for <?php the_time('Y'); ?>:</h2>
            <?php /* If this is an author archive */ } elseif (is_author()) { ?>
                <h2>Author Archive</h2>
            <?php /* If this is a paged archive */ } elseif (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) { ?>
                <h2>Blog Archives</h2>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <div class="entry">
            <br>    
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <p class="postmetadata">
                <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br />
                <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
                </p>

            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation">
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I already searching whole day and nothing working. what custom taxonomy template archive name i should use ? what code that i must change in this category.php to fulfill the needs of displaying the custom taxonomy archives(that can display all post that related to the clicked taxonomy) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a taxonomy.php for terms belonging to a custom taxonomy. You can just simply copy the template above and call it taxonomy.php

**EDIT**

You have one big fundamental flaw when registering your two taxonomies.

You **cannot** have white spaces in your custom taxonomy names, and this applies to function names and custom post type names as well. The following rules apply, and there is **no** work around these.

- names cannot contain white spaces or any special character.
- only lowercase letters are allowed
- if a name contains more that one word, you can **only** use underscores (`_`) to separate them. Do not use hyphens (`-`) as you will have issues later on
- see the codex for the limitation on character count for taxonomies and post types

So, in short, `kategori berita` and `tag berita` is invalid names. They should be `kategori_berita` and `tag_berita`. As I said, there are **no** work around to this problem. Your only solutions is to change your taxonomy names accordingly

Comment: Did you set `public` to `true` when you register your taxonomy? Also, did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: yes i have set the public property to true, i have flush the permalinks too but nothings changed. 
 
here is my code to register the taxonomy : jsfiddle.net/bkrs2bvk

Answer (score 1):

When the name of your taxonomy is "roles", you could create a file called taxonomy-roles.php. You can expand this with the term (in this example "ceo") like this as well: taxonomy-roles-ceo.php.

As @pietergoosen said you can just copy paste the code that you provided with in those files.

For more info on this you can check out the following link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: +1. Your answer is more comprehensive than mine. Did mine on the fly this morning before leaving home :-)

Comment: it still not working. it shows page not found. my taxonomy name is Kategori Berita so i created taxonomy-Kategori Berita.php as the custom taxonomy template.

Comment: @IPutuSaputra - would you mind sharing the code that creates the taxonomy? 

At the moment, you are using the label of the taxonomy in your taxonomy-*.php file. This should not be the name, but the identifier of the taxonomy (could be something like kategori-berita in your case - but this depends on how you've registered the taxonomy. If you share your code then I'll let you know what the name of your taxonomy-*.php file should be.